# Is there an official way to set kernel parameters in /boot/boot.scr in Debian?

Tags: boot, u-boot, kernel-parameters

I have installed Debian 12 on my Orange Pi Zero using a custom u-boot image. I notice that Debian has a file called /root/boot.scr which is rebuilt after apt upgrades. I had previously modified this boot script to include a boot parameter needed for Home Assistant.

Some people have done this on Armbian by adding the parameters to `/boot/armbianEnv.txt`.

Is there a way to permanently add a kernel parameter from within the Linux filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer:

Create the `/usr/share/flash-kernel/ubootenv.d/` directory and create a file in it. I called mine `/usr/share/flash-kernel/ubootenv.d/50-homeassistant-supervisor`, but you can call it whatever you like.

Inside the file, put your extra boot arguments like this:

```
setenv bootargs "${bootargs} <your boot arguments>"
```

Now you can run the `flash-kernel` command again using `sudo` and it will regenerate the `boot.scr` file.

## How I found this:

Well after a bit of digging through the logs during an install I found the line `Nov 27 11:01:13 in-target: Generating boot script u-boot image...`.

To find the script that had this line in it, i ran this command:

```
sudo grep -rnw / -e 'Generating boot script u-boot' > "search_result.txt"
```

The output of this command gave me the following line:

```
/usr/share/flash-kernel/functions:485:  printf "Generating boot script u-boot image... " >&2
```

Looking around that line of that `functions` file, I found reference to a ubootenv variable, populated by reading the contents of `/etc/flash-kernel/ubootenv.d` and `/usr/share/flash-kernel/ubootenv.d`. A bit of Googling later and I found a reference snippet doing what I wanted.